# Keras ConvLSTM2D Filters and Input channels: ValueError: number of input channels does not match corresponding dimension of filter, 7 != 1

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to build a convolutional neural network in Keras that incorporates a convolutional LSTM layer (ConvLSTM2D) in the middle for processing a sequence of GRAYSCALE images that come from a video. Each frame shape is (61,61,1) and sequences of these are passed in together so the overall input is (num_movies, num_frames, frame_height, frame_width, 1). The convolutional layers are pre-trained to autoencode images in the sequence, so all this is left is to train the recurrent LSTM layer. When I have just a single filter, the network works fine. Here is the network (all layers besides LSTM layer are TimeDistributed). The goal of the network is to predict future frames in the video given the current frames (i.e. pass in a sequence, move the sequence ahead n frames). I trained the convolutional part (autoencoder; see code below) separately to autoencode individual frames and am now trying to add in the LSTM to do sequence predictions.

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
time_distributed_1 (ZeroPad) (None, 34, 64, 64, 1)     0         
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_2 (Conv2D) (None, 34, 64, 64, 16)    160       
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_3 (MaxPool) (None, 34, 32, 32, 16)    0         
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_4 (Conv2D) (None, 34, 32, 32, 8)     1160      
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_5 (MaxPool) (None, 34, 16, 16, 8)     0         
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_6 (Conv2D) (None, 34, 16, 16, 8)     584       
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_7 (MaxPool) (None, 34, 8, 8, 8)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_8 (Conv2D)  (None, 34, 8, 8, 8)       584       
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_9 (MaxPool)  (None, 34, 4, 4, 8)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_10 (Conv2D) (None, 34, 4, 4, 1)       73        
_________________________________________________________________
rnn (ConvLSTM2D)             (None, 34, 4, 4, 1)       36        
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_11 (Conv2D) (None, 34, 4, 4, 4)       40        
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_12 (UpSample) (None, 34, 8, 8, 4)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_13 (Conv2D) (None, 34, 8, 8, 8)       296       
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_14 (UpSample) (None, 34, 16, 16, 8)     0         
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_15 (Conv2D) (None, 34, 16, 16, 8)     584       
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_16 (UpSample) (None, 34, 32, 32, 8)     0         
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_17 (Conv2D) (None, 34, 32, 32, 16)    1168      
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_18 (UpSample) (None, 34, 64, 64, 16)    0         
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_19 (Conv2D) (None, 34, 64, 64, 1)     145       
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_20 (UpSample) (None, 34, 61, 61, 1)     0         
=================================================================
Total params: 4,830
Trainable params: 36
Non-trainable params: 4,794
_________________________________________________________________
```

Everything runs when the number of filters in the ConvLSTM2D layer is one. However, when I try to adjust the number of filters in the ConvLSTM2D layer I get the error:

"ValueError: number of input channels does not match corresponding dimension of filter, 7 != 1"

where 7 is the number of filters I am trying to use.

Here I build the autoencoder.

```py
    autoencoder = Sequential()

    autoencoder.add(ZeroPadding2D(((2,1),(2,1)), input_shape = image_shape))  # (61,61, 1) --> (64,64, 1)

    autoencoder.add(Conv2D(16, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same'))         # (64, 64, 1) --> (64, 64, 16) 
    autoencoder.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), padding='same'))                          # (64, 64, 16) --> (32, 32, 16)
    autoencoder.add(Conv2D(8, (3,3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same'))      # (32,32, 16) --> (32,32, 8)
    autoencoder.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), padding = 'same'))                        # (32, 32, 8) --> (16,16, 8)
    autoencoder.add(Conv2D(8, (3,3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same'))      # (16,16,8) --> (16,16,4)
    autoencoder.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), padding = 'same'))                        # (16, 16, 4) --> (4, 4, 4)
    autoencoder.add(Conv2D(8, (3,3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same'))      # (16,16,8) --> (16,16,4)
    autoencoder.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), padding = 'same'))                        # (16, 16, 4) --> (4, 4, 4)
    autoencoder.add(Conv2D(1, (3,3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same'))      # (4,4,4) --> (4,4,1)


    # decode the lower dimensional representation back into an image
    model.add(Conv2D(4,(3,3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same')) # (4,4,1) --> (4,4,4)
    autoencoder.add(UpSampling2D((2,2)))                                    # (4,4,4) -> (16,16,4)
    autoencoder.add(Conv2D(8,(3,3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same')) # (4,4,1) --> (4,4,4)
    autoencoder.add(UpSampling2D((2,2)))                                    # (4,4,4) -> (16,16,4)
    autoencoder.add(Conv2D(8,(3,3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same')) # (16,16,4) --> (16,16,8)
    autoencoder.add(UpSampling2D((2,2)))                                    # (16,16,8) -> (32,32,8)
    autoencoder.add(Conv2D(16, (3,3), activation = 'relu', padding='same'))# (32,32,8) -> (32,32,16)
    autoencoder.add(UpSampling2D((2,2)))                                    # (32,32,16) -> (64,64,16)
    # want to use sigmoid as our final activation function to make the output more
    autoencoder.add(Conv2D(1, (3,3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')) # (64,64,16) -> (64,64, 1)

    autoencoder.add(Cropping2D(((2,1),(2,1)))) # (64,64,1) -> (61,61, 1)
```

Once the autoencoder is built, I train it on the autoencoding task and add in the LSTM layer.

```py
      num_layers = len(autoencoder.layers)

      model = Sequential()
      for i in range(num_layers // 2): 
          model.add(TimeDistributed(autoencoder.layers[i]))


      out_shape = autoencoder.layers[num_layers//2 - 1].output_shape

     # Convolutional LSTM 
     num_filters = 7 
     kernel_shape = (2,2)
     model.add(ConvLSTM2D(filters=num_filters, 
                         kernel_size=kernel_shape,
                         activation='tanh',
                         padding='same',
                         return_sequences = True,
                         name='rnn'))


     ''' #SimpleRNN
      model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))
     model.add(SimpleRNN(rnn_size, 
                   return_sequences = True,
                   activation = 'tanh',
                    name='rnn'))
     # NOTE: since the RNN changes size of output of the final Conv2D layer in encoding section, we somehow have
     #       to map the dimension back down. This is what the Dense layer below does
     model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(out_shape[1] * out_shape[2], activation = 'relu', name = 'ff')))
     model.add(TimeDistributed(Reshape((out_shape[1], out_shape[2], 1))))
     '''

      for i in range(num_layers//2, num_layers):
          model.add(TimeDistributed(autoencoder.layers[i]))

      # set non-reccurent layers to untrainable; we already trained these to be autoencoders, so the RNN
      # just has to learn how to move the object in the low dimensional space
      for layer in model.layers:
~         if not (layer.name == 'rnn' or layer.name == 'ff'):
              layer.trainable = False
```

When I change the number of filters to something besides one, I immediately get this error:

ValueError: number of input channels does not match corresponding dimension of filter, 7 != 1

I don't see why the number of filters has to be tied to the number of input channels? Can't we have multiple filters each with different kernels on the same input?

I have tried some common fixes like setting 'data_format=channels_last'